# Go to page without having to open a new window jquery

Tags: jquery

```
$(button).click(function(){
     window.open("www.wxample.com");
});
```

this code open page in new window.
Go to page without having to open a new window?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `window.location`

```
$(button).click(function(){
     window.location.href = "www.wxample.com";
});
```

See **[This Link](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/location)** for more details on how `location` works.